# How do I re-post the entire $_REQUEST to another endpoint?

Tags: php

I have an application that interacts with an outside API. When the remote serve posts a request containing specific status, I need to re-send the entire contents of that post to a different application through an external URL.

Is it possible to take the entire $_REQUEST and re-post it else where, or do I have to iterate through $_REQUEST and build a new array for posting where I need to?

Comment: Do you really need $_REQUEST? When all the data is posted then you better take $_POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should distinct between $_POST and $_GET values.

$_REQUEST represents all values that are coming by GET *and* POST, if one key is set in $_POST and $_GET value from $_POST have precedence when getting saved to the $_REQUEST array.

append everything that comes via $_GET to the URL and send everything from $_POST in the request body.

Answer (score 3):

$_REQUEST is an array. So yes you can post it where you need to. Just use cURL

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understand your question you're able to do it with CURL:

```
    $ch = curl_init("http://sitename.com/");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "field1=value1&field2=value2");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

where "field1=value1&field2=value2" is replaced with your args

Also you're able to get result of how operation is completed:

after $result = curl_exec($ch); use:

```
 $result_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
```

now in `$result_info['http_code']` is placed HTTP CODE. If it's 200 then SUCCESS (of course the code might be different in some cases - e.g. when it's artificially configured to another code)

Answer (score 1):

Using `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` can save the overhead of reencoding, if both segements are a POST method

Answer (score 0):

Lookup CURL, this should be rather easy:

http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) extension.